# Can I use an index as the source of an index in RavenDB

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to define an index in RavenDb that uses the output of another index as it's input but I can't get it to work.
I have the following entities & indexes defined.

SquadIndex produces the result I expect it to do but SquadSizeIndex doesn't even seem to execute.

Have I done something wrong or is this not supported?

```
class Country
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Player
{
    public string Id { get; private set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
}

class Reference
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class SquadIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Player, SquadIndex.Result>
{
    public SquadIndex()
    {
        Map = players => from player in players
                         let country = LoadDocument<Country>(player.CountryId)
                         select new Result
                         {
                             Country = new Reference
                             {
                                 Id = country.Id,
                                 Name = country.Name
                             },
                             Players = new[]
    {
        new Reference
        {
            Id = player.Id,
            Name = player.Name

        }
    }
                         };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Country
                                into g
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Country = g.Key,
                                    Players = g.SelectMany(x => x.Players)
                                };
    }

    internal class Result
    {
        public Reference Country { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Reference> Players { get; set; }
    }
}

class SquadSizeIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<SquadIndex.Result, SquadSizeIndex.Result>
{
    public SquadSizeIndex()
    {
        Map = squads => from squad in squads
                        select new Result
                        {
                            Country = squad.Country,
                            PlayerCount = squad.Players.Count()
                        };

        Reduce = results => from result in results
                            group result by result.Country
                                into g
                                select new Result
                                {
                                    Country = g.Key,
                                    PlayerCount = g.Sum(x => x.PlayerCount)
                                };
    }

    internal class Result
    {
        public Reference Country { get; set; }
        public int PlayerCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't. The output of indexes are not documents to be indexed.
You can use the scripted index results to chain indexes, but that isn't trivial.